# MS Graph Calendar event not getting created for specific O365 domains

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I currently have a Graph API based OAuth application in Azure AD that is used by our application to schedule events on behalf of the user using the OAuth access token flow.

This has been working fine so far but recently we have observed that there are few clients for whom the events are not getting created when the API call is made by the application. The event gets created however when the same payload is pushed through Postman. This is happening only for a few O365 domains and not for others. We are not able to figure out what could be a potential reason for this?

Anyone else who has faced something similar in the past or can point me towards some hypothesis?

Comment: Do you mean this happened only recently?

Comment: I would try the same with POSTMAN/Graph explorer against the problematic tenants and see if there's an issue or not. If there is an issue, check with O365 status from the portal or you may want to check with Microsoft support!!